Как получить Nan в си
Задача следующая: на си написать арифметическое выражение, содержащее только конечные числа типа double и четыре действия арифметики так, чтобы результат был равен NaN. В выражении не должно быть нулей, включая промежуточные результаты вычисления

Получите бесконечность сложением двух больших чисел, а дальше попробуйте разные операции над ней.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Надёжнее всего указать NaN в явном виде: std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() или NAN. Если так не хочется, попробуйте что-то вроде 1e+234*1e+234 - 1e+234*1e+234 (получаем NaN из разности бесконечностей одного знака). Если не сработает, то тогда попробуйте volatile double x = 1e+234*1e+234; double y = x; y -= x;, что должно поместить в переменную y значение NaN (по крайней мере в реализациях, придерживающихся требований Annex F стандарта языка C).

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double nan = (1e200 / 1e-200) / (1e200 / 1e-200);
    printf("nan is %lf\n", nan);
    printf("nan == nan is %d\n", nan == nan);
}


$ gcc -O2 -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c 

$ ./a.out 
nan is -nan
nan == nan is 0



@nörbörnën, я написал на самом деле (1e200/1e-200)/(1e200/1e-200).

Сейчас (1e200 / 1e-200) это не 0 (печатает inf). Но у меня (1e200 / 1e-200) / (1e200 / 1e-200) печатает -nan, а вот -((1e200 / 1e-200) / (1e200 / 1e-200)) печатает желанный nan

@avp, как там минус получается я не знаю. Знаю, что результат не равен сам себе, значит это NaN.

@avp "Ну что вы спорите, горячие финские парни!" (с) Есть же для таких случаев isnan...

@Harry, да, и в c++ и в c, что плюс, что минус, std::isnan возвращает 1

@avp Ну, обычно неважно какой из NaN'ов используется. Даже макрос NAN не обязан раскрываться в положительный NaN. Если же тут особый случай и требуется именно положительный NaN, то это следовало бы явно указать в вопросе. Особенно с учётом ограничений задачи. Ведь для бинарных арифметических операторов +, -, *, / знак результирующего NaN (если таковой будет получен в результате вычисления) не специфицируется. Пример.

@wololo, откровенно говоря, пока printf не напечатал -nan, я и не подозревал, что он может быть отрицательным. Просто поделился таким наблюдением, без всяких выводов о том, какой из nan-ов правильный.
